# producing 95% confidence- interval for sensitiity and specifity in spss

Tags: spss, confidence-interval, roc

I am using SPSS for producing ROC curve, but ROC cure does not give me the confidence-interval for sensitivity and specificity.

So if anyone can help me to produce confidence-interval for Sensitivity and specificity in SPSS will be the biggest help for me.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Version 26 has these statistics in its ROC ANALYSIS procedure (Note: NOT the ROC CURVE procedure you were using. This is a new one.)